# Data Mining Using Large XML Files

Tags: xml, nlp

Haven't used many .xml files, so looking for some expert help in determining how to start.

Trying to mine Stackexchange data from xml files located [here](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange)

There are separate files such as Posts, Users, Badges, PostHistory etc. that will ultimately need to be "joined" in order to derive any insights. Also, will need to apply NLP (Natural Language Processing techniques) to the comments, Posts etc.

What are my available options for (a) storing, and (b)processing the data? I know R, C, and SQL/databases.

Thanks in advance!